# How can i get id by using $this->uri->segment("parent_id") in kohana 3....

Tags: php, kohana, uri

it gives error  "ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Controller_Admin_Videocategory::$uri" . 
Please advice

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what version you use, but if its the newest and stable - [Kohana 3.2](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api), then:

```
$this->request->param('parent_id');
```

As explained in [here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Request#param).

Comment: `$this->request->param()` is available since 3.0, so its the only one right answer for a 3.x version ;)

Comment: He, he. But its in 3.2 as well! :D I did not say that it isn't in other versions! :D :D

Comment: when i use  if($this->request->param("parent_id")){
        $parent_id = $this->request->param("parent_id"); in view file it gives  following exception "ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Using $this when not in object context".....plese advice how to use this in view .... thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot use 'controller stuff' in the view (or maybe you can by using static methods?). Anyway, I would set new view variable like `View::factory('myview')->set('x', $this->whatever)` and then use `$x` in the view.

Comment: Come on, man! Its different question. Make new question and I will help you if none else will. :) Respect StackOverflow rules!

Comment: i am converting a project from kohana 2 to kohana 3. i replaced $this->uri->segment with $this->request>param('Id')   to get values from URI and it worked fine as advised earlier but now again when i am using the same in other modules i am getting following error mesasge:  HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: admin/videocategory/showForm/Id/669/s/1 ........please help me to resolve this.

Comment: please answer my last post. I am stuck at this point and unable to resolve this.